# How to get all the fields which do not contain specific 2 characters in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using sqlplus and I want to extract all contact numbers which contains any character apart from [0-9, '-','+', '(',')',' '] in SQL? I tried this

```
select VOICE from MERCHANT_MP_CONTACTS where (VOICE not like '%[0-9]%')
select VOICE from MERCHANT_MP_CONTACTS where (VOICE not like '%-%')
select VOICE from MERCHANT_MP_CONTACTS where (VOICE not like '%+%')..
```

Example:

Expected output

As i am using sql for the first time so i am not able to combine these conditions, Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: add some sample data & desired output which could more helpful to others to resolve your problem.

Comment: @KeshavTaparia whts difference between example & expected output ?

Comment: What about space char? for example `+65 8131 6259`line  exclude or include?

Comment: we also need to ignore spaces

Answer (score 1):

Demo: http://rextester.com/PECYN79110

isnumeric ensures remaining values are all 0-9. replaces eliminate the characters we want to allow as valid.

```
with cte (Voice) as (
 SELECT '+65 8131 6259' union all
 SELECT '+64-21-126-0024' union all
 SELECT '+66 955940641??' union all
 SELECT '+abc' union all
 SELECT '+651234'union all
 SELECT '+1(555) 555-5555')

SELECT cte.*
FROM cte
WHERE isnumeric(replace(
                replace(
                replace(
                replace(
                replace(voice,' ','')  --Eliminate spaces
                             ,')','')  --Eliminate )
                             ,'(','')  --Eliminate (
                             ,'-','')  --Eliminate -
                             ,'+','')  --Eliminate +
               ) = 0                   --show only those not numeric remaining.
```

Will not be speedy due to string manipulation; thus no index use.  However, you could create a computed column using the where clause expression then you could just reference the computed column isValidVoice with 1 or 0.  We put the cost for performance on the data save instead of subsequent queries.  So if read performance is a concern; but save performance can wait a fraction of a second more, then you could have better performance.

Alternatively you could make the where clause a function passing in voice and it simply returns if it's isValidPhoneNumber based on your rules.  This way the function can be used in multiple places; or as a computed column on multiple column/tables; but that too would be slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
select VOICE from MERCHANT_MP_CONTACTS WHERE (REPLACE(VOICE,' ','') like '%[^0-9+-]%')
```

Result:

```
VOICE
---------------
+66 955940641??
+abc
```

Comment: could you add some sample data? because I tested it with some data and seems working.

Comment: 050-3786-0222
050-5533-0888
09094623915
070-5346-9016
09037999463
0736221112
03-5375-0021
080-1406-4555
0120-676-869
010-2678-7653
09066065711

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: one strange thing is when i run select VOICE from MERCHANT_MP_CONTACTS where (VOICE not like '%[0-9]%'); i am getting "0957409904" this also as output

Comment: I tried and `0957409904` is not return. Maybe it has an invisible char.

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like below,  here you take all your **three not LIKE conditions and combine into a single one**, by using **UNION**

```
select VOICE from MERCHANT_MP_CONTACTS where (VOICE not like '%[0-9]%')
union
select VOICE from MERCHANT_MP_CONTACTS where (VOICE not like '%-%')
union
select VOICE from MERCHANT_MP_CONTACTS where (VOICE not like '%+%')
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156368/discussion-between-keshav-taparia-and-chetan-vasudevan).